# I want to show a page inside another page

Tags: php, laravel

Inside  first picture, the page name master.blade.php. Where I want to insert header.blade.php coding {{view::make('header')}}.
[image]

But the render page show this error,
saying "Class "view" not found
(View: C:\Users\Aman Ullah\ecomm\resources\views\master.blade.php)"
[image]

I tried different things but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not echo a blade file in another blade with `view::make`, you just need to use `@include` directive as demonstrated below:

```
@include('header')
@yield('content')
@include('footer')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a page inside another page, then you can simply include the required page like this:

```
@include('another_blade_file')
```